# I am having an issue with integrating an existing react component I found, into my app. "Attempted import error:"

Tags: javascript, reactjs

My goal is to bring an existing react component (below) that I found on the web, into my app to use. It is an animated navigation bar.

Here is the error message I receive after trying to compile the below code (snippets 2 and 3 below):

```
Failed to compile.

./src/components/Navbar.js
Attempted import error: 'react-responsive-animate-navbar' does not contain a default export (imported as 'ReactNavbar').
```

Maybe there is an issue with the library I installed? The creator had made this component 7 months ago, here - https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-responsive-animate-navbar.

Regardless, please see below for details on 1. the component I am trying to bring in, 2. the component in my code, refactored slightly and 3. the file I am importing this component into.

This is the component I found on the web. It renders an awesome navbar I would like to bring into my app. HOWEVER, I have never used the "class ... extends compoent" syntax. I have only used the "export default function name(){return()}" style.

```
npm install --save react-responsive-animate-navbar

import React from "react";
import ReactNavbar from "react-responsive-animate-navbar";
 
class Example extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <ReactNavbar
        color="rgb(25, 25, 25)"
        logo="https://svgshare.com/i/KHh.svg"
        menu={[
          { name: "HOME", to: "/" },
          { name: "ARTICLES", to: "/articles" },
          { name: "ABOUT ME", to: "/about" },
          { name: "CONTACT", to: "/contact" },
        ]}
        social={[
          {
            name: "Linkedin",
            url: "https://www.linkedin.com/in/nazeh-taha/",
            icon: ["fab", "linkedin-in"],
          },
          {
            name: "Facebook",
            url: "https://www.facebook.com/nazeh200/",
            icon: ["fab", "facebook-f"],
          },
          {
            name: "Instagram",
            url: "https://www.instagram.com/nazeh_taha/",
            icon: ["fab", "instagram"],
          },
          {
            name: "Twitter",
            url: "http://nazehtaha.herokuapp.com/",
            icon: ["fab", "twitter"],
          },
        ]}
      />
    );
  }
}
```

Here is the component since I have brought it into my app and slightly refactored it to fit the react syntax I have been using.

**./src/components/Navbar.js**

```
import React from "react";
import ReactNavbar from "react-responsive-animate-navbar";

export default function Navbar({ setSignedIn }) {
  return (
      <ReactNavbar
        color="rgb(25, 25, 25)"
        logo="https://svgshare.com/i/KHh.svg"
        menu={[
          { name: "HOME", to: "/Explore" },
          { name: "ARTICLES", to: "/articles" },
          { name: "My Profile", to: "/profile" },
          { name: "CONTACT", to: "/contact" },
        ]}
        social={[
          {
            name: "Linkedin",
            url: "https://www.linkedin.com/in/nazeh-taha/",
            icon: ["fab", "linkedin-in"],
          },
          {
            name: "Facebook",
            url: "https://www.facebook.com/nazeh200/",
            icon: ["fab", "facebook-f"],
          },
          {
            name: "Instagram",
            url: "https://www.instagram.com/nazeh_taha/",
            icon: ["fab", "instagram"],
          },
          {
            name: "Twitter",
            url: "http://nazehtaha.herokuapp.com/",
            icon: ["fab", "twitter"],
          },
        ]}
      />
    );
  }
```

And finally, here is where I am attempting to import this component for it to render onto an actual page.

**./src/Pages/IntroPage**

```
import React from "react";
import Navbar from "../components/Navbar";
import Categories from "../components/Categories";

export default function ChooseACategory({ setSignedIn }) {
  return (
    <div>
      <Navbar setSignedIn={setSignedIn} />
      <Categories />
    </div>
  );
}
```

I suspect the issue is with my refactoring from the "class ... extends component" syntax to the "export default function name" syntax (which I am more familiar with). I understand there is not a big difference between the two, but I would rather keep my code for this project uniform. Any help is welcome!

Answer (score 1):

There was nothing wrong with you refactor, because you did not use any states. I installed that package, with nothing changed. The same wrong message as yours appeared when I started it. I suspect this package itself is not runnable.

Answer (score 0):

For my situation, I found a workaround solution, it not renders and works properly using the highlighted edit in the screenshot below. Thanks!

```
   import React from "react";
    import * as ReactNavbar from "react-responsive-animate-navbar";
    import Logo from "../Assets/Media/ToolioLogoSmall.png"
     
    
    export default function Navbar({ setSignedIn }) {
      console.log(ReactNavbar.ReactNavbar) //Edited, fixed issue.
      return (
        <div style={style.background}>
          <ReactNavbar.ReactNavbar style={style.background}
            color="rgb(25, 25, 25)"
            logo={Logo}
            menu={[
              { name: "HOME", to: "/Explore" },
              { name: "ARTICLES", to: "/articles" },
              { name: "My Profile", to: "/profile" },
              { name: "CONTACT", to: "/contact" },
            ]}
            social={[
              {
                name: "Linkedin",
                url: "https://www.linkedin.com/",
                icon: ["fab", "linkedin-in"],
              },
              {
                name: "Facebook",
                url: "https://www.facebook.com/",
                icon: ["fab", "facebook-f"],
              },
              {
                name: "Instagram",
                url: "https://www.instagram.com/",
                icon: ["fab", "instagram"],
              },
              {
                name: "Twitter",
                url: "http://www.twitter.com/",
                icon: ["fab", "twitter"],
              },
            ]}
          />
                
          </div>
        );
      }
```

Comment: Please show code as text, in addition to or instead of, showing code as an image. Search engines, and more importantly, humans with visual impairments, will be unable to take advantage of the information in your answer because it is in an image.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the source for that package, it does not contain a default export. It has:

`export const ReactNavbar` without the default.

Try importing the named component instead of as a default:

`import { ReactNavbar } from` instead of `import ReactNavbar from`